How to ask Firefox to open two or more windows (with specific URLs) on startup?
I have a use case say I am using one window as a window to browse the internet, another one having a web application open. How can I make Firefox open two windows with specific URLs on startup?
I know how to open different tabs on startup (by separating URLs using the pipe symbol in the start-page settings) - is there another symbol/command, to tell Firefox to open two or more URLs in separate windows instead of different tabs in one window?
